# How to remove extra character (+) from URL - ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, regex, asp.net-mvc, url, character-encoding

In my view in table i did same replacing to add `br` its look like this :

```
@if (rma.Kundenavn.Contains("Region Syd - Sygehus Lillebælt"))
{
    <td class="tdft">@Html.Raw(rma.Kundenavn.Replace("Region Syd - Sygehus Lillebælt", "Region Syd - <br /> Sygehus Lillebælt"))</td>
}
else
{
    <td class="tdft">@rma.Kundenavn</td>
}
```

and result will be like this:

```
 Region Syd - <br> Sygehus Lillebælt
```

and when I copy that text which is contains `br` and than I try search after it I will get problem and my search tells me can't find it.

When this happened my URL it will be like this :

```
Lukkedesager?searchingLukkedesager=Region+Syd+-++Sygehus+Lillebælt
```

as you can see there is extra `+` after `dash`

When I remove that `+` I will get the result back.

My question is how can `remove that extra + after dash` , Can anyone help me or point me in the right direction ! Thanks in advance :)

Here is related data :

View:

```
  @Html.PagedListPager(Model, pageNumber => Url.Action("Lukkedesager", new
                        {
                            pageNumber,
                            searching = Request.QueryString["searchingLukkedesager"]
                        }))
```

Comment: Remove the trailing space after the tag: `"Region Syd - <br />Sygehus Lillebælt"` in your replacement string.

Comment: Why are you using HTML-formatted text in the query string then? Does the `td` have an `onclick` handler? Use data attributes instead.

Comment: @CodeCaster nup td doesnt have an onclick handler , but would tell me which data attr should i use instead ! :)

Comment: Then how does that text in which you add a `<br />` end up in the query string?

Comment: @CodeCaster sorry i forget to mention in my last cm , i just checked my code i used data attr and it will added from my form   using (Html.BeginForm("Lukkedesager", "User", FormMethod.Get))
                            {

                                Html.TextBox("searchingLukkedesager", null, new { class = "form-control", id = "tx1" })

                                <button class="srhbtn" id="sh1" type="submit">SØG</button>



                            }

Comment: @AlexK. and thanks to you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have surrounded the `<br />` with spaces (so on both sides). Spaces are translated to `+` when put in a query string, so the two spaces become two `+`-es.

The fix is to remove the space that follows the `<br />`, like this:

```
.Replace("Region Syd - Sygehus Lillebælt",
         "Region Syd - <br />Sygehus Lillebælt")
```

Comment: ohhh didn't see that :) anyway thanks for help Peter